# Online (incremental) logistic regression in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

In Spark MLlib (RDD-based API) there is the `StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD` for incremental training of a Logistic Regression model. However, this class has been deprecated and offers little functionality (eg no access to model coefficients and output probabilities).

In Spark ML (DataFrame-based API) I only find the class `LogisticRegression`, having only the `fit` method for batch training. This doesn't allow for a pattern of model-saving, reloading and incremental training.

Needless to say some applications benefit greatly from incremental learning. Is there any solution available in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark ML, when you call LogisticRegression.fit() you get a LogisticRegressionModel. You can then add the LogisticRegressionModel to a [Pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html) and save/load the pipeline for incremental training.

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(lr))
model = pipeline.fit(data)
model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/saved_model")
```

If you want to train the model with streaming data or apply it to streaming data, you can define a [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) dataframe and pass it to the pipeline.

For example (taken from the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets)):

```
// Read all the csv files written atomically in a directory
val userSchema = new StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")
val csvDF = spark
  .readStream
  .option("sep", ";")
  .schema(userSchema)      // Specify schema of the csv files
  .csv("/path/to/directory")    // Equivalent to format("csv").load("/path/to/directory")
```

Comment: I don't understand how this allows you to use the pipeline to train the model iteratively on mini batches. When you call `fit` I thought the model the pipeline was supposed to learn from scratch, am I wrong?